# Is there a way to run loop for a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

So, this is the structure that I want. class Rect has been already defined. Here, the number of Rect is 5 and is repeated 5 times. But I want it to repeat it n times where n is the input. The rcta[] is float value which is double the number of n which will also be entered accordingly. And everything should be stored in the array tmp_rect_list. How can I do this?

```
tmp_rect_list = [Rect(rcta[i],rcta[i+1]),Rect(rcta[i+2],rcta[i+3]),Rect(rcta[i+4],rcta[i+5]),Rect(rcta[i+6],rcta[i+7]),Rect(rcta[i+8],rcta[i+9])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
tmp_rect_list = [Rect(rcta[i], rcta[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(rcta), 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, grouping the values in `rcta`:

```
rcta = [...]

tmp_rect_list = [Rect(a, b) for a, b in zip(*[iter(rcta)] * 2)]
```

Example using `tuple`s instead of `Rect`s:

```
In [1]: rcta = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [2]: tmp_rect_list = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(*[iter(rcta)] * 2)]

In [3]: tmp_rect_list
Out[3]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```